# Matlab houghlines returns X,Y coordinates out of image boundary

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I tested Matlab's Hough transform for detecting lines.
I came up with an odd behavior in the following code:

```
clc; clearvars; close all;
I = zeros(100,100);
I(50:70,25) = 1;
[H,T,R] = hough(I);
P = houghpeaks(H,1);
lines = houghlines(H,T,R,P,'MinLength',10);
disp([ 'Coordinates for beginning of line (x,y) = '...
    ,num2str(lines.point1(1,2)),',',num2str(lines.point1(1,1))]);
disp([ 'Coordinates for ending of line (x,y) = '...
    ,num2str(lines.point2(1,2)),',',num2str(lines.point2(1,1))]);
disp([ 'Length of detected line = ', num2str(norm(lines.point1 - lines.point2)) ]);
```

One minor quibble is that the original line length is 21 pixels while the houghlines found it to be 18. By setting 'Theta' resolution to a higher precision by substituting

```
[H,T,R] = hough(I);
```

to

```
[H,T,R] = hough(I,'Theta',-90:0.01:89.99);
```

I reach a value of 20 pixels. Setting values other than 1 to 'RhoResolution' in the Hough transform function messes the results much more.
So this is a bit annoying - the length of the lines is off by 1 (I tested other lengths as well).

What's more bothering is that the original image is 100x100 pixels and if I don't set Theta to a higher resolution, the end points (in my initial example provided here) are off the grid (x coordinate of 108, giving that the terminology here is that the rows are x-axis, the columns are y-axis)!

And if I do set 'Theta',-90:0.01:89.99 the beginning and end points are also completely off from the original points (though they're still within the image boundaries).

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!